# iphone - How to prevent app to block while downloading data

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xmpp

Im developing an app with XMPPframework. When Im downloading the vCards of the users(the pictures, names etc)  the app blocks until it has downloaded the data of all the people connected in that moment.

I need that to be in a second thread(I havent used mutithreading yet) so that the app is reponsive to new touches and show an Activity icon while the data is being downloaded.

I've heard of Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) but I've also heard of other ways, which one would you reccomend?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that if you're writing from scratch, there's no reason to go with anything else than GCD. It's well integrated with many examples on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do work on a second thread with something like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  /* your code to download the vCards goes here */
  /* if you are explicitly updating a UI element then you would have to perform that on the main thread so you would do something like this */
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     label.text = @"some text";  // or any other code that updates a UI element
  });
});
```

If all you want to do is download the vCard data in a second thread and assign the results to a variable then there is no need for the second call to dispatch_async() because you aren't performing any actions on UI elements.

Comment: Let me see, so you are saying that the first block will download the data but not show it, and when all that data is downloaded, I will execute the code to show the pictures with the second block, is that right?

Comment: That depends on how your code is written to show what you download.  If you are explicitly making calls that update the UI, like say updating the text of a label or something like that then inside of the first dispatch_async you would have to put the second dispatch_async, and put your code to update the UI in that one.  I'll edit my answer to try and make it a bit more clear.